# Not able to convert string to int, not able to get length of array element in java

Tags: java, android

I have a String **amount** having value **496988,(11874),952743,(35175),33425,(654)**

I'm splitting it so I can get individual element in `String[] casesDataArr`

`String[] casesDataArr = textView.getText().toString().split(" ");`

Now I just need the integers from array and remove the **(** , **)**

I tried this

```
active = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[0]);
delActive = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[1].substring(1, casesDataArr.length));

discharged = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[2]);
delDischarged = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[3].substring(1, casesDataArr.length));

death = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[4]);
delDeath = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[5].substring(1, casesDataArr.length));
```

but getting error in last line:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=6

I know it's due to the *casesDataArr.length* but when I write *casesDataArr[5].length* it shows redundant text. I'm missing something do guide me. Having any doubts comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 issues:

- You are using the legnth of the array instead of the length of each string. What should have lead you to this is that you use the same length for each index, isn't that weird?)
- The index of the last character of a String is not `string.length()`but `string.length() -1` as index starts from 0.
- You don't use `casesDataArr[1]` but use `casesDataArr[0]` twice

  ```
  active = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[0]);
  delActive = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[1].substring(1, casesDataArr[1].length()-1));

  discharged = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[2]);
  delDischarged = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[3].substring(1, casesDataArr[3].length()-1));

  death = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[4]);
  delDeath = Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[5].substring(1, casesDataArr[5].length()-1));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, you can remove non-numeric characters:

```
String input = "496988,(11874),952743,(35175),33425,(654)";

List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : input.split(",")) {
    values.add(Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("\\D", "")));
}

System.out.println("values: " + values);
```

**Result:**

> values: [496988, 11874, 952743, 35175, 33425, 654]

Answer (score 1):

**Given:** String of value : *496988,(11874),952743,(35175),33425,(654)*

First remove "**,**":

```
String casesDataArr[]=textView.getText().toString().split(",");
```

Your array is now as follows:

**index 0:** 496988

**index 1:** (11874)

**index 2:** 952743

**index 3:** (35175)

**index 4:** 33425

**index 5:** (654)

Second, remove "**()**" if present:

```
for(int i=0;i<casesDataArr.length;i++){

if(casesDataArr[i].contains("(")&&casesDataArr[i].contains(")")){
casesDataArr[i]=casesDataArr[i].substring(casesDataArr[i].indexOf("(")+1,casesDataArr[i].indexOf(")"));
}

}
```

The obtained array is:

**index 0:** 496988

**index 1:** 11874

**index 2:** 952743

**index 3:** 35175

**index 4:** 33425

**index 5:** 654

To fetch a number in the `int` type from an index of the array, just write this:

```
int myInteger=Integer.parseInt(casesDataArr[0]);
```